# How to validate in availability using jquery validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I want validate post availability in database using jquery validation functionality, I have validated using below code, Where need to put a ajax validation  before submit the form

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#conference_form").validate({
   rules: {
        postcode: "required",
         name: "required",
         address: "required",
         date: "required",
         description:"required",

    },
    messages: {
         postcode: "Please enter valid post code",
         name: "Please enter venu_name",
         address: "Please enter address",
         date: "Please enter date",
         description: "Please enter description",
    }
  })
});
```

Please any one help.

Comment: You want to check postal code availability in DB?

Comment: Responase in json data not true or false

Comment: Can you please share your json response?

Comment: {"post_code":"AB13","full_post":"AB13 545s","price":"10","status":"success"}

Answer (score 0):

This is sample code for postal code availability check in DB using jquery validate.

```
//Javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#conference_form").validate({
       rules: {
            postcode:  {
                required: true,     
                remote: {
                    url: "postalcode_availability.php",
                    type: "post",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
                    dataType:"json",
                    data: "{'postcode': '" + $('#postcode').val() + "'}",
                    dataFilter: function(data) {
                        var json = JSON.parse(data);
                        if(json.status == "true") {
                            return true;
                        }else{
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }           
              },
             name: "required",
             address: "required",
             date: "required",
             description:"required",

        },
        messages: {
             postcode: :{
                 required: "Please enter your postcode.",
                 remote: jQuery.validator.format("{0} is not exist.")
             },          
             name: "Please enter venu_name",
             address: "Please enter address",
             date: "Please enter date",
             description: "Please enter description",
        }
    })
});


//postalcode_availability.php
// For reference I have made check postal code in an array but you can make code for check in DB as per your requirement.
<?php       
    $postcodeArray = array('382481','382810','382845'); 

    $postcode=$_POST['postcode'];
    $isError = "";
    if (in_array($postcode, $postcodeArray))
    {       
        $isError "true"; //exist
    } 
    else
    {       
         $isError "false";  //Not exist
    }
    echo json_encode(["isError"=>$isError]);exit;
?>
```

Comment: @Sarath S please check updated answer. I have deal with json response in it.

Comment: @Sarath you want to validate based on the "status":"success" part of the json respons. Right?

Comment: Please try with updated answer. Modified as per your response.

Comment: To use the `remote` method, you **do not need `dataType`** because that's the default already built into the plugin. You **do not need `data`** because, by default, the plugin already sends the value of the field being validated. And you certainly **do not need `dataFilter`** because the plugin is designed to handle a JSON response from the server and triggers validation accordingly. So your `return true` and `return false` within `dataFilter` is superfluous at best... at worst, it might even toggle the `remote` method instead of triggering validation.

Comment: Please refer to documentation:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/